# Python csv file / next() / while loop

Tags: python, csv

This should be really easy, but as i am still a noob i'm stuck.

While loop is running over an amount of time steps. I want to insert some variables from a csv file, every cell in the csv file has 3 integers(x,y,angle), which have to be sperated and passed to the simulation.

This is my try, but as you see i still have to learn a lot, but maybe someone can help me with this problem.

```
...........step = 0
while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0:
      simulationStep()
       with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as f:
         lines = f.next() 
         new = lines.split(",",)
         x = new[0]
         y = new[1]
         angle = new[2]   

       vehicle.moveTo(vehid01, x, y, angle)  
       step += 1........
```

I want to store one line per time step; pass these variables. So when the next time step begins, the next line of the csv file should be read, passed and so on. So new timestep, new line does not work.x,y angle values won't change.

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you meant to open the file outside the while loop, so you get a new line every time.

Comment: You're opening myfile.csv, read one line, then iterate to open the file *again*, read the same line, iterate to reopen the file, read the same line, etc. Consider opening the file *outside* the while loop.

Comment: Awesome that works thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
...........step = 0

with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0:
        simulationStep()
        lines = next(f)  # compatible with Python 3
        new = lines.split(",")
        x = new[0]
        y = new[1]
        angle = new[2]   

        vehicle.moveTo(vehid01, x, y, angle)  
        step += 1........
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `csv` module to delegate the parsing.

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    step = 0
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0:
        simulationStep()
        x, y, angle = [float(i) for i in next(reader)]  # reader.next() for 2.x
        vehicle.moveTo(vehid01, x, y, angle)  
        step += 1
```